# Acesso Negado phpMyadmin error 2002

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Estou precisando usar o phpmyadmin no xampp, mas esta me retornando este erro

> #2002 - Arquivo ou diretorio nao encontrado O servidor não está respondendo (ou o soquete do servidor local não está configurado
>   corretamente).  A conexão para o controle do usuário, como definida
>   nas configurações, falhou.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Tipo de ligação

Com base nos detalhes fornecidos pelo erro, experimenta aceder ao ficheiro:

```
/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

E procurar pela linha:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

Alterando `tcp` para `socket`.

---

## Localização do mysql.sock

Outra questão com esse erro prende-se pelo PHP não conseguir localizar o ficheiro socket do MySQL. Localiza o teu ficheiro:

```
/etc/php/php.ini
```

E procura pela linha:

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-socket
mysql.default_socket = /caminho/para/mysql.sock
```

Onde está `/caminho/para/mysql.sock` no texto de exemplo, coloca o caminho correcto para o ficheiro `mysql.sock` no teu sistema.

---

<sup>Créditos das duas soluções para @SemiBz e @vaquerito respectivamente no archlinux [neste tópico](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=90133).</sup>

Comment: entao zuul esse arquivo soket eu nao tenho ele?? tem como criar

Comment: @user3677610 corre num terminal `mysql_config --socket` para veres onde está o ficheiro. Ele é criado automaticamente quando o MySQL Deamon é iniciado, deverá estar no teu sistema a não ser que tenha sido bloqueado por um outro processo :/

Comment: cara testei aki e nada

Comment: conhece outras maneiras??

Comment: @user3677610 Experimenta no terminar correr: `locate mysql.sock`.

Comment: entao correu o caminho do mysql.sock, porem nao alterou nada eu modifiquei nos arquivos php.ini, coonfig.inc.php, e no my.cnf, mas o erro esta persistindo

Comment: vc tem outra ideia??

Comment: @user3677610 Qd dizes "correu o caminho" estás a dizer que ele localizou o ficheiro e deu-te o caminho correcto para actualizares o ficheiro `php.ini`, certo? E dizes também que actualizaste o `php.ini` com o caminho correcto e que após _restart_ continua a dar o mesmo erro, certo?

Comment: sim sim, fazendo esses processos todo o erro permaneçe

Comment: zuul obrigado pela atenção mas consegui arrumar o erro, acabei trocando a porta do mysql obrigado

Comment: @user3677610 Boas notícias então! Aproveita e coloca a tua solução como uma resposta e marca a mesma como aceite. Vai ajudar futuros visitantes com o mesmo problema.

Comment: ok simplesmente abri o arquivo my.cnf que fica dentro da lampp/etc e alterei as portas 3306 para 3307 pronto

Comment: Parabeeens! @ SemiBz e @vaquerito ajudou muuuito deu super certo alterar o php.ini graças a Deus consegui! Obrigado....