# Estou tendo problema de aceder meu phpmyadmin usando meu Android, estou usando WampServer

Tags: android

Ao colocar o ip do meu computador no browser do celular, diz que não tenho permissão para aceder, peço ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se esta solução te ajuda.   http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/acesso-negado-phpmyadmin-error-2002

Comment: Provavelmente não está com permissão de acesso à pasta no servidor, reveja as permissões da pasta, tente colocar permissão de execução para todos e teste: ex. chmod 777 /path/to/your/phpmyadmin